# Pull data from a variable array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So basically I'm doing a Jeopardy project for school(which I'm sure we've all suffered through). After a LOT of tinkering, I got the data from the API (jservice.io) to go into my main data variable(categories). Now, I need to pull that data out in a nice organized way. I really just need to figure out what actually shows data then I'm sure I can go from there. Here's the code:

```
let url = "https://jservice.io/api";
let urlCat = `${url}/categories?count=100`;
let urlClues = `${url}/clues`;
let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

const NUM_CATEGORIES = 6;
// categories is the main data structure for the app; it looks like this:

//  [
//    { title: "Math",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "2+2", answer: 4, showing: null},
//        {question: "1+1", answer: 2, showing: null}
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    { title: "Literature",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
//        {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    ...
//  ]

let categories = [];


/** Get NUM_CATEGORIES random category from API.
*
* Returns array of category ids
*/

//Pull category links at random and store them into the "categories" variable.
async function getCategoryIds() {
    for (let i= 0; i < NUM_CATEGORIES; i++) {
        let res =  await axios.get(`${url}/category?id=${randomNum}`);
        categories.push(res);
    }
}


/** Return object with data about a category:
 *
 *  Returns { title: "Math", clues: clue-array }
 *
 * Where clue-array is:
 *   [
 *      {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
 *      {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
 *      ...
 *   ]
 */

//get the data from the categories chosen in the getCategoryIds function.
function getCategory(catId) {
    let test = categories.data; // Obviously, this did not work. 
    console.log(test);
}
```

The very end is what I'm working on, and trying to get the data to show. I also thought of doing something with counting the array somehow like i = 0, i++ sort of thing.

Thank you SOF!

So far, ive tried the following:

```
//get the data from the categories chosen in the getCategoryIds function.
function getCategory(catId) {
    let test = categories.data; // Obviously, this did not work. 
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: As categories is an array so you need to specify indexes like categories[0], which will give you first object of the array. Then you can use the dot operator to access the keys of the object like categories[0].title

Comment: Where is your call to `getCategoryIds()`? Are you using `await` or `.then()` before calling `getCategory()`?

Comment: @Madhavmishra thanks for this, I'll work on it. I would need to find a way, then, to pull each array (I.E. [0][1][2][3] etc.) and display it's contents one after another in the way I want. I'm not sure writing something like [0,1,2,3,4,5] to pull my 6 arrays would work, because again I need each of them separate. They'll eventually be a board in HTML.

Comment: @Barmar this is all the code I have. So there is no call, or `await` or `.then`. I will look into this.

Comment: If you don't call the functions they never execute.

Comment: That's actually very much my bad. I've been using an html button to call it. I am so sorry. `<button onclick="getCategoryIds()">Start Game</button>` and `<button onclick="getCategory()">Test button</button>`

However, I got it using `forEach`! Adding code to help the next person: `function getCategory(catId) {categories.forEach((id) => {}}`

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding is correct, you want to show the data after you pull from categories.

As I check your attempt here.

```
function getCategory(catId) {
    let test = categories.data; // Obviously, this did not work. 
    console.log(test);
}
```

I see that you are getting data from categories(*categories.data*), But as you can check the data of categories, there's no *data* on it.

After some time of checking your codes. I use and produce this kind of attempt.

Maybe this could help you or not, but hoping it helps you to get an attempt that will answer your question.

```js
let url = "https://jservice.io/api";
let urlCat = `${url}/categories?count=100`;
let urlClues = `${url}/clues`;
let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

const NUM_CATEGORIES = 6;
// categories is the main data structure for the app; it looks like this:

//  [
//    { title: "Math",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "2+2", answer: 4, showing: null},
//        {question: "1+1", answer: 2, showing: null}
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    { title: "Literature",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
//        {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    ...
//  ]

let categories = [];


/** Get NUM_CATEGORIES random category from API.
*
* Returns array of category ids
*/

//Pull category links at random and store them into the "categories" variable.
async function getCategoryIds() {
  let status = document.getElementById("status");
  let formField = document.getElementById("form-fields");
  let waitmsg = 'Getting data. Please wait...'
  console.log(waitmsg);
  status.innerText = waitmsg
    for (let i= 0; i < NUM_CATEGORIES; i++) {
        let res =  await axios.get(`${url}/category?id=${randomNum}`);
        categories.push(res.data);
        waitmsg = 'Done!'
    }
  console.log(categories,'categories')
  console.log(waitmsg);
  status.innerText = waitmsg
  formField.style.display = 'block';
}

/** Return object with data about a category:
 *
 *  Returns { title: "Math", clues: clue-array }
 *
 * Where clue-array is:
 *   [
 *      {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
 *      {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
 *      ...
 *   ]
 */

//get the data from the categories chosen in the getCategoryIds function.
// function getCategory(catId) {
//     let test = categories.data; // Obviously, this did not work. 
//     console.log(test);
// }

//get the data from the categories chosen in the getCategoryIds function.
function getCategory(catId) {
    //let test = categories.data; // Obviously, this did not work. 
    //console.log(test);
    
  catId = document.getElementById("catId")
  let output = document.getElementById("output")
  let question = '<div>';
  let number = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<categories[catId.value].clues.length; i++){
      number = number + 1; 
      question += number + '. ' + categories[catId.value].clues[i].question + '<br>';
      question += 'Answer:<span><i> '+ categories[catId.value].clues[i].answer + '</i></span><br>';
      question += '</div>';
  }
  output.innerHTML = question;
  console.log('Questions generated.')
  document.getElementById("fields").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="fields">
  <button onclick="getCategoryIds()">Start Game</button>
  <p id="status"></p>
  <div id="form-fields" style="display:none;">
    <p>
      Now, input number 1-5 in the textfield. <br>
      Because you declare <b>NUM_CATEGORIES = 6</b>,<br>
      Index start with 0 so <i>Number: 1-6</i> is equal to <i>Index: 0-5</i>
    </p>
    <p>Example you input 3 from categories.</p>
    <input type="number" id="catId" value="3"/>
    <button onclick="getCategory()">Test button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="output"></p>
```